# ValueError: Cannot assign "": "Message.name" must be a "CustomUser" instance

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am building a live chat for my website and encountered this error message while trying to save messages to database. I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLwu1NqU1rE&ab_channel=CodeWithStein) tutorial to create the live chat and am now trying to implement it to my site. The difference is that I do not need different rooms and I want only authorized users to access the chat. The problem comes because I use foreign key on my Messages model to create a link with CustomUser model. I am using channels.

template where the data comes from:

```
const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
        )

        chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e);

            const data = JSON.parse(e.data)

            if(data.message) {
                document.querySelector('#chat-messages').innerHTML += ('<b>' + data.username + ': </b>' + data.message + '<br>')
            } else {
                alert('Empty!')
            }

        }

        chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log('The socket closed unexpectedly');
        }

        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
            const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input')
            const message = messageInputDom.value

            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message,
                'name': {{request.user}},
            }))

            messageInputDom.value = ''
        }
```

code used for saving into database in consumers.py

```
def save_message(self, name, message):
        Message.objects.create(name=name, content=message)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from .managers import CustomUserManager


# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    steam_id = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, db_column='steam_id')
    player = models.TextField(null=True)
    user_coins = models.FloatField(default=0.00)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='status')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='isstaff')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='issuperuser')

    USERNAME_FIELD = "name"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added',)
```

Comment: where do you call ```save_message``` function?

Comment: I call it inside receive function like this
`
async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(data)
        message = data['message']
        name = data['name']

        await self.save_message(name, message)
`
@shivankgtm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pass a string and reference it to an object of `CustomUser` class. You'll have to pass an instance of it.
First get the relevant instance by using `id` or a suitable unique attribute,(hope the `name` is unique)

```
def get_object(self, name):
    return CustomUser.objects.get(name=name)
```

And then pass it in your `save_message(self, name, message)` method,

```
def save_message(self, name, message):
    user_obj = self.get_object(name)
    Message.objects.create(name=user_obj, content=message)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am new to Django and couldn't figure out what was happening myself.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your `Message` model, `name` is a `ForeignKey` to `CustomUser` model. So problem is in your `save_message` as you provide `name` as `string` but it must be `CustomUser` instance.
So change `save_message` in your `consumers.py` from this

```
def save_message(self, name, message):
    Message.objects.create(name=name, content=message)
```

To

```
def save_message(self, name, message):
    Message.objects.create(name=user_obj, content=message) <--- add custom user object accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

first take name from customuser then put value in message

```
msgname = CustomUser.objects.get(name)
message = Message.objects.create(name = msgname, content = message)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.